# Define a variable as a substring of a changing file basename

Tags: batch-file, cmd, variable-assignment

The file I want to work with is in `C:\folder1\subfolder2` but has a file basename containing a variable date, i.e. `company_yyyyMMdd.zip`

I want to define a variable named `fileyear`, by searching `C:\folder1\subfolder2\company*.zip`, containing the four digit year string.

So far my code is:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%a in ("C:\folder1\subfolder2\company*.zip") do set fileyear=%%a:~7,4% & echo %fileyear%
```

I expect `echo %fileyear%` to output `2022`

I did a test in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) like this:

```bash
set FILENAME=company_20221215.zip
echo %FILENAME:~7,4%
```

It said `2022` just like I wanted.

`7` means start at the 7th position and the `4` means read the next 4 digits.

Comment: Always use a `setlocal` following the `@echo off` as it disposes of changes to the environment when the batch terminates. You cannot substring metavariables like `%%a`. You nrrd to assign them first to a user-variable. You also need to beware of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947).

Comment: There is absolutely no need ever to use a single line in a batch file. It doesn't make the code any more efficient, nor does it make it simpler to read. It would also be better to use `company_*.zip`, and even better `company_????????.zip`, as your wildcard/glob

Comment: What change do I need to make to my code so it outputs 2022?

Comment: The advice for which changes you need to make has already been given. We aren't here to do it for you, please make an attempt.